# Find earliest interval start date and extract interval (R, lubridate)

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate

I have a dataframe with four possible class S4:intervals, like so:

```
 id  int_a           int_b             int_c              int_d
 1   2013--2015      2011--2012        NA--NA             2014--2014
```

what I need is to sort on the earliest start date that can be extracted with int_start() and then store this interval (or the length) as e.g. first_int as a new variable in the dataset and reiterate for second, third, and fourth.

the expected output would be:

```
id  .. first_int      sec_int          third_int          fourth_int
 1  .. 2011--2012     2013--2015       2014--2014         NA--NA
```

i have added a chunk of my dataset below

```r
library(lubridate)
so <- structure(list(int_a = new("Interval", .Data = c(24192000, 
                                                          52704000, 0, 64022400, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), start = structure(c(1286841600, 
                                                                                                                             1327276800, 1157068800, 1370995200, NA, NA, NA, 1296172800, NA, 
                                                                                                                             NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     int_b = new("Interval", .Data = c(NA, 2505600, NA, NA, 
                                                          53222400, 7862400, NA, NA, 0, 116812800), start = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                        1402531200, NA, NA, 1397433600, 1307577600, NA, NA, 1366329600, 
                                                                                                                        1320278400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                                    tzone = "UTC"), int_c = new("Interval", .Data = c(NA, 
                                                                                         NA, 19353600, NA, NA, 41472000, 0, NA, NA, NA), start = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                             NA, 1287446400, NA, NA, 1238025600, 1433203200, NA, NA, NA
                                                                                         ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                     int_d = new("Interval", .Data = c(3024000, 9331200, NA, 
                                                          0, 8899200, 36374400, 0, 3196800, 18748800, 28771200), start = structure(c(1316044800, 
                                                                                                                                     1396828800, NA, 1466640000, 1457568000, 1290038400, 1444694400, 
                                                                                                                                     1321315200, 1381968000, 1438300800), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure about what you are truly looking for here, but I think this might solve your challenge. I'm a bit confused about the part of your post referring to

> i can sort on start date but I fail to sort on one feature of the interval and then extract the whole.

Using `purr::` and `lubridate::`, you can do the following:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(purrr)

so <- structure(
  list(
    int_a = new("Interval",
                .Data = c(24192000, 52704000, 0, 64022400, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA),
                start = structure(c(1286841600, 1327276800, 1157068800, 1370995200, NA, NA, NA, 1296172800, NA, NA), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                                  tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"),

    int_b = new("Interval", 
                .Data = c(NA, 2505600, NA, NA, 53222400, 7862400, NA, NA, 0, 116812800), 
                start = structure(c(NA, 1402531200, NA, NA, 1397433600, 1307577600, NA, NA, 1366329600, 1320278400),
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                  tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"),

    int_c = new("Interval",
                .Data = c(NA, NA, 19353600, NA, NA, 41472000, 0, NA, NA, NA),
                start = structure(c(NA, NA, 1287446400, NA, NA, 1238025600, 1433203200, NA, NA, NA), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                                  tzone = "UTC"),tzone = "UTC"),

    int_d = new("Interval",
                .Data = c(3024000, 9331200, NA, 0, 8899200, 36374400, 0, 3196800, 18748800, 28771200), 
                start = structure(c(1316044800, 1396828800, NA, 1466640000, 1457568000, 1290038400, 1444694400, 1321315200, 1381968000, 1438300800), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                                  tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")),

  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

earliest_start_interval_list <- map_at(.x = so, .at = 1:ncol(so), ~ min(lubridate::int_start(.x), na.rm = TRUE))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for responding!

i was unclear, sorry. i need to 
(a) find the earliest start date between the four intervals in a row
(b) then extract the whole interval that starts with this date and store it in a new column
(c) repeat the steps for second, thrid, and fourth(=last) earliest starting date

i have edited the original post for clarity

Comment: I was trying to do something like: `earliest_start_interval_row <- pmap(.l = so, .f = ~min(lubridate::int_start(.x), na.rm = TRUE))` (or using `min()` instead of `pmin()`), but this way `NA` is returned everytime the first value is `NA`. I'm unable to progress any further, but maybe someone else can chime in here.

What if you calculated your `min`from the raw interval start values before you put everything together?